# NoSuchMethodError org.hibernate.Session.createQuery при обращении к базе

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, build

После создания артефакта появляется такая проблема. В артефакте создаю папку libs и запихиваю туда все библиотеки. В манифесте указываю

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> Class-Path: /libs
>
> Main-Class: Main

После успешной генерации папка libs с банками появляется рядом с запускаемым jar.

Comment: NoSuchMethodError - это всегда конфликт версий зависимостей.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Я в Идее нажал выбрал добивать плагин hibernate, и не добавил зависимость в pom. Добавил зависимость и теперь вроде работает, спасибо.